# notice: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 "

Tags: 7

I have created a module in my project.

Everything works well on my local server. but when I upload my project on internet host I faced this alert message "**Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0** " in all pages. (it seems module works but I don't know why is the cause of this notice message)

This message happened on this line

```
if(isset($data['content']['whois_lookup_data']['#markup']))
```

Also, in my local server my PHP version is 5.3 while in internet php version is 5.2

Is this error related to version of PHP ?

Comment: The error probably _doesn't_ happen on that line, since that line does not attempt to access anything at an index of `0`. The problem is likely somewhere else, and not related to your PHP version. No worries about the edit, I like capital letters :)

Comment: But I tested, in server with PHP 5.2.17 error happened. but in server with PHP 5.3.18 this error doesn't happened.

Comment: That'll be down to your error_reporting settings - one server is set to report notices, the other isn't

Comment: in both server, error_reporting is set to ALL

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, that notice exists in both 5.2 and 5.3, so if your settings are the same on both servers you'll get the same results. At the moment they aren't, as you can see by the message being missing from one server. It definitely isn't caused by php version, only settings. If you post a more complete snapshot of the code , we might be able to see where the problem is. FYI error_reporting should be `E_ALL`, not `ALL`. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: I must agree with @Clive, it's impossible to have this error at that exact line. But maybe server reports it wrong? Maybe CRLF was interpreted as 2 lines, not one? Can you post +-10 lines of context?

Comment: Dear Clive, I am using Acquia Dev Desktop. I found that I can set php version in my software. there are two php versions. one is 5.2.17 and another is 5.2.18. error_reporting in both of them is set to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE, But when I swtich to php5.2.17 I got notice message and when I switch to php5.3.18, the message is dissipated. I think this notice message is directly to PHP version.

Comment: `~E_NOTICE` means you **don't** want to see notices. Why one version ignores it and the second does not is a mystery, but you should remove it (leave only `E_ALL`) and only set it up again when your development is done.

Comment: Exactly - if your settings say "don't show notices", but one version of PHP that you have installed is ignoring that, you need to fix that problem first. It's not something we can help with here as it's not related to Drupal in any way

Comment: I agree but it is confusing issue, the both PHP versions have the same configuration for "error_reporting" but in one of them notice is show and in another it doesn't show.

Comment: Your last comment should be a bugreport to your hosting company or your admin.

Comment: it is not hosting. it is my Acquia Dev desktop. are you sure that old php 5.2.17 doesn't have error with this line ?????  if(isset($data['content']['whois_lookup_data']['#markup']))

Comment: This line is way too simple to have any doubts. And the mere fact that your PHP ignores it's configuration means that something went wrong at way deeper level than Drupal. Anyway, localhost hosting is hosting too, if simplified ;) I mean, the fact you are an admin does not change the fact that error reporting inconsistency is a hosting, not Drupal issue.

Comment: Ok, let us forget php versions. I want to know why this line "if(isset($data['content']['whois_lookup_data']['#markup']))" causes this notice? it is a very simple conditional IF command about $data['content']['whois_lookup_data']['#markup'] exists or doesn't.